# Ошибка описания класса

Tags: классы, c++

Код программы:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3973519/sorted%20set.cpp

Проблема заключается в строке 129, на ней вылазит ошибка о отсутствии описания функции.
Однако описание на 117 строке. В чем проблема не понимаю.

Comment: Почему вы пишите, к примеру, `node *search(int x)`?<br>
ИМХО - для функций, лучше `node* search(int)`, а для переменных `node *var1, *var2`

Comment: стилистический вопрос, возможно вы правы, попробую ваш вариант

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не правильно используете звездочку.
Вместо:

```
node set::*mergetrees(node *first, node *second){
```

Надо:

```
node* set::mergetrees(node *first, node *second){
```

Comment: спасибо, действительно не понимаю как я такую глупость написать мог.

Answer (score 1):

```
node* set::mergetrees(node *first, node *second)
```

у вас нет метода *mergetrees.